# How to automatically add a row above a particular cell?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula

I'm sending some data from Zapier to Google Sheets and every time Zapier creates a new row, all formulas from that row are gone. I'm looking for a script that would allow the following solution:

I set up Zapier to always update row no. 2 (Row 1 is for table headlines) => Once Zapier fills the data in this row, a script automatically creates a new row above it, pushing all the other rows one place lower (with formulas remaining in all cells in row 2).

Answer (score 1):

Use **`ARRAYFORMULA`** in row 1 and calculate rest automatically regardless of newly inserted rows. Example:

[image: 0]